# split and trim in ant?

Tags: regex, ant

Honest. ANT is new for me.

I have a string.

I need to use this string, lets say (A;B;C;), as

A
B
C

but i also need to loop through these values and pass them to another ant target!

loop for A
then for B and finally for C

the number of values in string is random also.
i searched the network and found out its quite easily possible with ant-contrib.

but as usual, i can't use ant-contrib for some reasons from some other guys.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [script task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) with builtin javascript engine (included since Java 1.6.06, so no extra libraries or ant addons needed)
and full access to ant api. Here's a very simple snippet :

```
<project>

 <property name="foo" value="A;B;C"/>

 <script language="javascript">
  <![CDATA[
  // a simple String replace action
  var clean = project.getProperty('foo').replace(';', ' ');
  println(clean);

  // create a property for further processing in the buildscript
  project.setProperty('foobar', project.getProperty('foo').replace(';', ' '));

  // for loop
  var items = project.getProperty('foo').split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   println(items[i]);
  }
  ]]>
 </script>

 <echo> $${foobar} => ${foobar}</echo>

</project>
```

output :

```
[script] A B C
[script] A
[script] B
[script] C
[echo]  ${foobar} => A B C
```

For reuse wrap your scripting in a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html).

**--EDIT after comment --**
It is possible to call ant tasks programmatically, some example using the [echo task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) :

```
<project>

 <property name="foo" value="A;B;C"/>

 <script language="javascript">
  <![CDATA[
  // for loop
  var items = project.getProperty('foo').split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    print = project.createTask("echo");
    print.addText(items[i]);
    print.execute();
  }
  ]]>
 </script>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] A
[echo] B
[echo] C
```

Comment: Hi @Rebse, it worked very smoothly. just one thing i want to know if I can call a target and pass the values instead of println(items[i]) -> is it possible?

Comment: thanks for the response Rebse ... but didn't got the time to implement this..till now ... once again thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use antcontrib:

```
 <antcontrib:propertyregex property="trimmedprop"
     input="${untrimmedprop}"
     defaultValue="${untrimmedprop}"
     regexp="\s"
     replace=""
     global="true" />
```

For splitting, I'm guessing you're going to use a "for" loop, you can do that with antcontrib also:

```
 <property name="letters" value="a,b,c,d,e"/>

 <antcontrib:for list="${letters}" param="letter">
  <echo>Letter ${letter}</echo>
 </antcontrib:for>
```

To get antcontrib in your project:

```
 <project default="test" xmlns:antcontrib="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">
    <typedef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib" classpath="/local/path/to/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
```